# Calculating pmf of (consecutive) hits to an enemy

Tags: probability

Let's say we are playing a game where there is an enemy who dies after getting $5$ damage points in total. We are hitting the enemy consecutively until he dies. Our hits can do $1, 2, 3$ or $4$ damage points. All hits are equally possible, so doing $1$ damage point has $\dfrac{1}{4}$ probability, same for $2, 3$ and $4$ dmg points. Hits are independent. Let the random variable $Y$ to describe the total number of hits needed so the enemy dies. Obviously $Y$'s range is from $2$ to $5$.

How can i calculate the mass $p_Y(y)$? Does the order of hits matter?

Comment: These numbers are small enough that you can brute-force a solution by enumerating all possibilities.

Comment: @amd Indeed, i have already done this and got the solution. I am just asking if there is any other more clever(/sooner) way to do this.